# Why was my edit removing superfluous meta content rejected?

Tags: discussion, editing, suggested-edits

I recently [made a suggested edit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/110906) on a question, *removing* the following content:

> You may think that this question is nonsense. But to me it's NOT. I'm really curious why. So, down voting is your choice, but I don't see a reason to down vote. Please, if you really are down voting, comment your reason. Thanks.

My suggested edit was promptly rejected with one of the standard reasons: losing the original intent of the question. Why? This content is superfluous to the subject of the question and meta content shouldn't be in the question anyway.

Comment: [The edit has now been made anyway…](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/197486/revisions)

Comment: Yeah, that should have been approved.

Comment: if the OP rejects an edit before it gathers the necessary votes one way or the other, doesn't that make it show as rejected?

Comment: @gatherer Yes, an OP's approve/reject is binding, yet this is not what occurred here, as two rejects were reached.

Comment: Note to self:  click through links, THEN open mouth.

Comment: I did not approve / reject this edit. I don't have this privilege. Oh, and I'm the OP.

Comment: @Arceus Yes, I was aware that it wasn't you who rejected it, and perhaps if it had been you I wouldn't have been so concerned (see my comment on the answer). Also, FYI you don't need suggested edit review privileges to review edits made to your own posts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sometimes bad edits get approved when they shouldn't. On the other hand, good edits sometimes get rejected when they shouldn't too. The latter is what's happened in this instance. There's nothing wrong with the edit that you made, and it certainly didn't deviate from the original intent of the post. Indeed, as others have mentioned, a *diamond moderator subsequently made that exact edit anyway*.

Fortunately a single rejected edit isn't going to do you any harm, so while it's a little frustrating it's not really anything to worry about.

Comment: Thanks; I understand a single reject won't get me suspended but it's the principle that two users didn't agree with my edit which was particularly concerning, when having made over 3000 edits across SE I may have been doing something wrong!

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281510/did-i-correctly-edit-this-question

Comment: @cybermonkey I have seen that question, but that seems to be a different case, where the meaning of the question could, at first glance, have actually have been modified. Code edits in questions/answers are always on a fine line, and I try to avoid code edits even where I have full edit privileges.